# Ungoogleble machine-code or otherwise hard to read EUID part

Tags: zsh, uid

Not sure whether obfuscated, machine-code or something else. Please, let me know what the part is for and how to read it. The part is from the [file](http://www.dotfiles.org/~gregf/.zshrc).

```
###############################################################################
# Set prompt based on EUID
################################################################################
if (( EUID == 0 )); then
    PROMPT=$'%{\e[01;31m%}%n@%m%{\e[0m%}[%{\e[01;34m%}%3~%{\e[0;m%}]$(pc_scm_f)%# '
else
    PROMPT=$'%{\e[01;32m%}%n@%m%{\e[0m%}[%{\e[01;34m%}%3~%{\e[0;m%}]$(pc_scm_f)%% '
fi
```

could someone break it a bit more into parts?

1. What does the conditional `EUID == 0` do?
2. I get an error about `pc_scm_f`, using OBSD, is it some sort of value in other OS?
3. the `\e` starts some sort of logical part, what do the rest do?

Comment: That is actually my config. I wouldn't do things this way any longer, but Ferruccio has the correct answer. You should use the autoload colors module if you plan to do anything like this.

Comment: gregf: thank you for sharing, killed all of it, in the end, but got some good ideas such as the OS-independent-settings.

Comment: My latest configs are [here](https://github.com/gregf/dotfiles) if you're interested. To answer your other questions. EUID == checks the Effective User ID to be sure you are root. I was setting a different prompt if the user was root. pc_scm_f was a old function I used to get the git branch I was on. \e is an escape to start processing the color codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](http://www.dotfiles.org/~gregf/.zshrc) which seems to contain the whole thing in proper context. 
Also tells me Ferruccio is right: It's an ANSI escape string, used to change the style of the command-prompt. \e starts the escape codes, the rest is the code itself. Used to be very popular in the old DOS time, especially with a game called NetHack. It's just pretty-print for your console.